# Making some items in navigation drawer disable/not selectable

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer with several items in it. But I want some of them to be non-selectable when I click on it.
I've tried to change the adapter, but the selector is still appear when I click it. I've also tried to change the listview properties, but I couldn't find the method that I wanted.

Is there any solution for this problem? Or perhaps another way to achive it? Any tutorials would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I done in the past it to just block the launching of the item in a if statement. No reason to hide it unless you really need to. You can also change the item color to make it look disabled.

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       int tempHold;
       tempHold=mSelectedItem;
       mSelectedItem=position;

        switch (position) {
        ...
        case 2:
            //For if no user is logged into app, do not launch
            if (userID.equals(getString(R.string.no_user_logged_on))) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_worklist_no_user), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //reset your drawerSelector to previous item
                mSelectedItem=tempHold;
                break;
            }
            //Log.wtf("userID: ","\""+userID+"\"");
            fragmentCreator(position, param1, "");
            break;

        default:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position "+position+" not configured " +
                    "yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
            }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear); //Close drawer after selection
    }
}
```